# Enrage and damage calculation mid phase

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I attack with [Bellowing Aegisaur](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBellowing%20Aegisaur%5d) and other creatures and they choose to block all of my creatures.

Would I, as the attacker, get to assign combat damage, and can choose Bellowing Aegisaur's attack to be first making its Enrage go into effect placing +1/+1 counters on my other creatures before their damage is calculated?

Conversely, if I block with it can I ask them to assign damage in order and if they choose Bellowing Aegisaur before some of my other blockers would they receive their counters before their damage calculation?

Answer (score 4):

No, all damage is dealt simultaneously.

> 510. Combat Damage Step
>
> > 510.1. First, the active player announces how each attacking creature assigns its combat damage, then the defending player announces how each blocking creature assigns its combat damage.
> >
> > 510.2. Second, **all combat damage that's been assigned is dealt simultaneously**. This turn-based action doesn't use the stack. No player has the chance to cast spells or activate abilities between the time combat damage is assigned and the time it's dealt.

This would only work if the creature blocking Bellowing Aegisaur had first strike or double strike.

Comment: You need for Aegisaur's blocker to have first strike, not the dino itself.